# Re-migrate or unlock question

Tags: discussion, reopen-request, migration, locked

**Updated question** (I originally misread the history and Ben N picked it up.)

The following question originated on Server Fault and was migrated here: [Accidentally left a small form factor PC in ~100F (37c) temperature for several hours - is it safe to use? [on hold]](https://superuser.com/q/1147375/364367).

A number of people thought this was too opinion-based, and in a literal sense, it is.  However, there really isn't much opinion required to answer what was asked.

- The equipment was in a powered-off state in 89 degree F temperature (100 F in the title, but that difference doesn't affect the answer), which is well within equipment tolerances.
- The OP has no understanding of what might even be potential risks, so asks whether a surge protector or UPS is needed to protect other equipment from damage, or even whether the equipment should simply be trashed to avoid risks.
- The question received a number of quality answers.
- For an "opinion-based" question, there was no difference in opinion among the answers.
- The question is generally applicable to many users and the subject matter is on-topic here rather than Server Fault.

The question was voted closed as opinion-based.  Since the question had been migrated here, that action caused the migration to be rejected.  So now it is back at Server Fault, and closed there, and closed and locked here (if it is even technically still here at all).

Personally, I would vote to reopen this one, and another user indicated the same in comments on that thread.  In its current state, though, the community can't voice its opinion on whether the question should be reopened.

As things stand, it will get deleted on both sites.  The only opportunity for the question and answers to avoid deletion would be here.  It looks like this would require moderator action at this point, and given the history, there may not be a mechanism to bring it here closed and allow the community to vote to reopen.

So I'll just request moderator judgement and intervention to migrate the thread back here, or unlock it, if it's deemed an acceptable question.

Comment: Only a mod can unlock it AFAIK.

Comment: Note that it fortunately won't get deleted here - locked questions are never [roomba'd](http://superuser.com/help/roomba), nor are ones with upvoted answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question has been unlocked so that the community can vote on whether it should be reopened.

As it stands though the question could do with some cleanup to break up the Great Wall of Text and care needs to be taken to ensure that answers are of *good* quality.

As it is an "easy" question it can, and in fact already does, have several answers stating exactly the same answer of "it is fine" with no qualification of **why** that is the case. I would prefer people to cite sources, maybe an Intel data sheet showing the temperature limits of their processors or other components.

Bearing that in mind I have also posted a notice on the question and will protect it should it start receiving too many low quality answers.

Comment: Thanks for unlocking it and the suggestions.  Just in the process of shutting down, but I'll get into this when I crank up again on Monday.

Answer (score 3):

When a question is migrated and then closed or deleted on the target site, the migration is considered "rejected." That causes the target site's copy to be locked and the source site's copy to be unlocked but left closed with the generic off-topic reason. (See the timeline [here](https://superuser.com/posts/1147375/timeline) and [on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/posts/815821/timeline).)

The [rationale](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218414/295684) for immediately locking closed migrated questions is that questions in need of improvement shouldn't be migrated because that dumps one site's problem on another's community, which is rude. In this case, though, it's debatable whether the question needs any improvement before it's acceptable here. I agree with you in that it's not primarily subjective/opinion-based. Answers to it can cite facts.

Leaving it in this state would be a shame, since the answers are good, while the current unlocked copy on Server Fault has no answers. (Therefore, re-migrating it would give us a version without the answers.) The question is clearly off-topic on Server Fault - so there's no danger of it being reopened there and duplicating the communities' efforts - while it's on-topic here. It would be great if a Super User moderator unlocked it. Conveniently, doing that [would automatically change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268199/295684) the migration notice from the "rejected" one to a normal one.

Relevant MSE: [Treat question migrations better for almost-fits-but-not-quite questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223486/295684)

Comment: The plot thickens.  Looks like I misread the history.  Apparently, this originated at Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

[Accidentally left a small form factor PC in ~100F (37c) temperature for several hours - is it safe to use?](https://superuser.com/questions/1147375/accidentally-left-a-small-form-factor-pc-in-100f-37c-temperature-for-several) was closed as primarily opinion based. In a discussion about this with user.dz he remarked:

> the "I don't know = close" mentality on almost all stackexchanges nowadays is sad

I agree with this and would nominate the question to be reopened if it was unlocked.

The question has been reopened.

Comment: "the "I don't know = close" mentality on almost all stackexchanges nowadays is sad" - I issued the last vote, despite knowing about this meta because of the quality of the answers the question was receiving.  The fact I did or didn't know the answer never wasn't taken into consideration when I used that vote.

Comment: I noticed just don't want to be placed into a group